# iBatis | Dynamic Sql | remapResults - random error

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

We have a dynamic sql, where select clause and table name are variables.
Following are the 2 queries and Integer 5 is the difference between both the versions.
Note: We have specified remapResults=true from the beginning itself.

```
SELECT Int1, Int2, Int3, Int4, Date1
FROM   Table1
WHERE ...

SELECT Int1, Int2, Int3, Int4, Int5, Date1
FROM Table2
WHERE ...
```

Code executes as expected 95% of the time and throws non-reproducible exceptions at times.

Exception 1: net.sf.cglib.beans.BulkBeanException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Exception 2: net.sf.cglib.beans.BulkBeanException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Please note that the parameter map is a class and the result is also a class.

From the logs, its clear that the fields in the select query aren't being honored properly by ibatis and its trying to map date to integer for a case where date is the 4th element and the 5th integer is not even present in the select clause. May be caching the result pattern. But isn't remapResults supposed to fix this ? And also it works almost always and results in random exceptions, thus making it difficult to zero in on the issue.

We have considered other options to get rid of the dynamic sql, but would like to identify the problem before moving to other options.

Any idea what the issue/fix could be ? Are we supposed to use remapResults along with resultMap and not resultClass ?

Comment: Seems to be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-770 bug.